# After installing Xampp correctly it's not open into browser in Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, mysql, xampp, mysql-connection

Firstly I text the command on my terminal like sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
[sudo] password for tayef: 
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.2.34-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

Secondly I text like sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

After doing that of above xampp GUI comes like..please, click picture link below

[image]

then

[image]

After click on Xampp home panel on Go To Application it shows like the following

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/tayef/.Xauthority which is owned by tayef.)
[11635:11635:1106/191936.161137:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/tayef/.Xauthority which is owned by tayef.)
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: iceweasel: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: seamonkey: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: mozilla: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: epiphany: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: konqueror: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: chromium: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: chromium-browser: not found
[11665:11665:1106/191936.206660:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 869: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://localhost:80'
```

Comment: 1. Don't install Xampp on Kali. Use a proper general-purpose distribution instead of this security pentesting one. 2. Don't try to run Firefox as the root user

Comment: Only solution here is highly appreciable. Please put useful information rather than unbound task proposal....Thank you

Comment: It is useful information. You shouldn't be installing things like Xampp on Kali

Comment: Okay.. I take your suggestion good but whats the other ways

Comment: Sorry! what did you mean Panki

Comment: I came here for the solution not just commenting

Comment: Kali is aimed at experts - you are not an expert. You're making things hard for yourself and aren't listening to advice.

Comment: You wanna say like that after i change my OS then come to work with xampp properly....as I am not a expert...Panki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start it in kali linux following Command suggested to be used....

Step-1

Open the terminal then put the following  command....

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

By using GUI come up on the screen we can start all the needed services by pressing start all easily rather than using command like

```
sudo service mysql start

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Step-2

open any preferred browser and then put the text or url like...

```
http://localhost:80/phpmyadmin/
```

This above steps would be useful to Kali-linux user since I have been facing opening problem for past few days

Following error I have seen to start the application by pressing on Xampp home tab

```
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/tayef/.Xauthority which is owned by tayef.)
[24952:24952:1107/205040.567917:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  ($XAUTHORITY is /home/tayef/.Xauthority which is owned by tayef.)
```